# How can I get Access to Parse (de)Serialized JSON

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

I have an API that is passing data back to an MS Access Module.  The data that's coming back is JSON, but it's in this format:

```
{   
    "<Field1>k__BackingField":"SomeValue"   
    "<Field2>k__BackingField":"SomeOtherValue" 
}
```

I have found a few Parsers available for access that works with the standard JSON format, but nothing that seems to work with this.  I'm actually not even sure what this is... I know it has to do with being Serialized, but... beyond that, I'm clueless... perhaps there's some modification to an existing utility like the one below that I should try?:
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: Can't you remove Automatic Property syntax from your Class?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... what class?

Comment: I have an API that is passing data back to an MS Access Module. Did you write this API?

Comment: Ah, yes. So, you're referring to the class that's instantiated to supply the "response." I'll have to look into how to remove Automatic Property in .Net. I just didn't know what to do aboit it because I didn't know what I was looking at.

Comment: That's not valid Json

Comment: Correct, if you wrote the class, you created your properties like `string abc {get;set;}`, when serialized these properties throw BackingField syntax.

Comment: @cyboashu - wow... you need to post this the answer so's I can mark it and upvote it.